# Compile boost as a dll

Tags: boost

Is there a way to compile the boost libraries into a dynamic library rather than using them as static libraries?

Comment: what is the `hello world` code about?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post my questions without accompanying code, so I added that silly thing.

Comment: Perhpas you should have supplied your command line/bjam invocation rather than a fake program....

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to compile the boost libraries into a dynamic library ...

Yes. Use `link=shared` with `bjam`. See [Building Boost DLLs](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Building-Boost-DLLs-td2695730.html) on the Boost mailing list. Also see [Invocation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html) in the Boost docs.

Answer (score -1):

Boost libraries are mostly header only. You don't need to compile them at all, just include their header.